# Ionic 3 - Button change his own color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i have a problem with my ionic project.

`home.html`

```
<button ion-button block round large style="height: 35px" (click)='Clicked()' [color]="ColorButton">{{ TextButton }}</button>`
```

`home.ts`

```
ColorButton: string = "primary";
TextButton: string = "It's blue !";
Clicked(){
    this.ColorButton = "danger";
    this.TextButton = "It's now red !"
}
```

But when i click on the button nothing happens, i have to change page and come back to see button changes.
How can i do to make button change himself ?

Comment: i resolve it please check it @Rombond

Comment: please check it...

Comment: What you are saying button color change problem ? i will check it by clicking Envoyez() function and also change this.ColorButton = "secondary"; then first button background change .

Comment: Envoyez() is to reset color and text, and it works perfectly but the other button doesn't work

Comment: i used browser cordova not working on browser ......... so i will check manual functionality ........ are you check in real device ?? its can be check in real device .......

Comment: I have an iPhone SE and a Samsung Note 2 to test my project

Comment: so you can set  this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component); after this.adress = device.id;

Comment: I will try it a few minutes later

Comment: so what result ??

Comment: @Utpaul no it doesn't work too :/

Comment: @Utpaul have you an idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: I think your subscribe method not working properly....

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Actually in Debutmanuel you need to show alert to see color change or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really found a solution, but i found an alternative, i set my command to change my button inside a timeout function and it works